# Moq SetupSequence with multiple setup assertions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am writing some tests where the class I'm testing depends on `HttpClient`. To mock that I am mocking a `HttpMessageHandler` and pass that to the `HttpClient` constructor.

To accomplish this I have a base class:

```cs
public class HttpTestBase
{
    protected static readonly string BaseAddress = "https://test.com";

    protected readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    protected readonly Mock<HttpMessageHandler> _httpMessageHandlerMock;

    public HttpTestBase()
    {
        _httpMessageHandlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpMessageHandlerMock.Object);
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
    }

    protected void MockHttpResponse(HttpResponseMessage message, string expectedPath, HttpMethod expectedMethod)
    {
        _httpMessageHandlerMock
          .Protected()
          .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
            "SendAsync",
            ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(request => AssertRequestParameters(expectedPath, expectedMethod, request)),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
          .ReturnsAsync(message);
    }

    private bool AssertRequestParameters(string expectedPath, HttpMethod expectedMethod, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
       // Throw an exception if the method or path does not match what is expected.
    }
}
```

And then a test looks as follows, in a test class inheriting this test base:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task GetAvailableLicenseCount()
{
    // Arrange
    var licenses = new JsonObject
    {
        ["total_seats_consumed"] = 4500,
        ["total_seats_purchased"] = 5000
    };

    MockHttpResponse(
        new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, Content = new StringContent(licenses.ToJsonString()) },
        expectedPath: "/enterprises/enterprise/consumed-licenses",
        expectedMethod: HttpMethod.Get
    );

    // Act
    var result = await sut.GetAvailableLicenseCount();

    // Assert
    result.Should().Be(500);
}
```

This works well when a method only performs a single call. Some methods perform multiple calls in a sequence. I have solved that partially, but I would still like to have the assertion in the setup (e.g. when I call `AssertRequestParameters`).

To support multiple calls in a chain, I instead did this in the base class:

```cs
protected void AddHttpMockResponse(HttpResponseMessage message, string expectedPath, HttpMethod expectedMethod)
{
    _responseMocks.Enqueue(new HttpMock
    {
        Response = message,
        Assertion = new Assertion { ExpectedPath = expectedPath, ExpectedMethod = expectedMethod }
    });
}

protected void MockHttpResponses()
{
    _httpMessageHandlerMock
        .Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
            "SendAsync",
            ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .ReturnsAsync(() => _responseMocks.Dequeue().Response);
}
```

As you can see I have removed the assertion in the setup, because it seems that the assertions collide and I get the wrong return value from the mock.

To use this, I refactored the test as follows:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task GetAvailableLicenseCount()
{
    // Arrange
    var licenses = new JsonObject
    {
        ["total_seats_consumed"] = 4500,
        ["total_seats_purchased"] = 5000
    };

    AddHttpMockResponse(
        new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, Content = new StringContent(licenses.ToJsonString()) },
        expectedPath: "/enterprises/enterprise/consumed-licenses",
        expectedMethod: HttpMethod.Get
    );

    MockHttpResponses();

    // Act
    var result = await sut.GetAvailableLicenseCount();

    // Assert
    result.Should().Be(500);
}
```

This also works well for multiple responses from the same mock.

However, I would like to be able to mock multiple responses where the response is determined by what I use in the `Setup` of the mock. The reason I want to do this is that I cannot use `Verify` on `HttpMessageHandler` as the method is [not accessible to me](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpMessageHandler.cs#L17).

Is it possible to achieve a dynamic return value based on what is done in the setup of the mock?

Comment: The question specifies Moq, but if it didn't I could probably show you an answer that doesn't depend on Moq and might be a lot easier.

Comment: @ScottHannen it doesn't necessarily have to be Moq, it's just that I've used it in these tests. As long as I have maintainable tests I'm happy

Comment: In your test cases you setup the HttpClient to return with OK response. Then you make assertion against Internal Server Error. Is it intentional?

Comment: @PeterCsala the result is an integer indicating license count (`5000 - 4500 = 500`). So the result is successful and indicating that

Comment: @jokarl Apologize, I thought it is a status code. My bad, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you'll want something like this:

I recently had to do a similar thing and found the below article very helpful. Check the 'Mock HttpMessageHandler Using Moq' section. It shows you how to return a `HttpResponseMessage` object you create, which is what I think you might want.

https://code-maze.com/csharp-mock-httpclient-with-unit-tests/

Field on your class

```
private readonly Mock<HttpMessageHandler> _httpMessageHandlerStub;
```

In your setup (constructor or a separate method)

```
_httpMessageHandlerStub = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();

var httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpMessageHandlerStub.Object);

_sut = new SomeService(
    httpClient,
    anotherDependency
)
```

And then you can configure the below in each test

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetListAsync_Successfully_Uses_Api_Key()
{
    var unauthorisedResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        Content = new StringContent($"'{_apiKeyHeaderName}' header not found or API key is incorrect")
    };

    var successResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<SomeDto>()))
    };

    // Return 200 if api key header is present and the value is correct.
    _httpMessageHandlerStub.Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
            "SendAsync",
            ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x => x.Method == HttpMethod.Get && x.Headers.Any(h => h.Key == _apiKeyHeaderName && h.Value.FirstOrDefault() == _apiKeyHeaderValue)),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .ReturnsAsync(successResponseMessage);

    // Return 401 is api key header is not present or api key value is incorrect.
    _httpMessageHandlerStub.Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
            "SendAsync",
            ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x => x.Method == HttpMethod.Get && !x.Headers.Any(h => h.Key == _apiKeyHeaderName && h.Value.FirstOrDefault() == _apiKeyHeaderValue)),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .ReturnsAsync(unauthorisedResponseMessage);

    var result = _sut.GetListAsync();

    // Assert stuff...
}
```

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Not quite what I’m looking for unfortunately. My issue stems from the need of having multiple setups that collide. As you can see from my code above I’m already mocking the message handler. I found another way to verify mocks with Protected and As<> while digging into this that will probably help.